# Should we have separate function handler for all intents if number of intents are more than 200

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

What if I have more than 100 intents including the followup intents. Should we write separate handler for each 100 intent and call a common function from the handler function. Is it correct?

Here we want to have common function with intent name as parameter, because all we do is fetch the response from database.

Shall we have parameterized function in intentmap set or have separate handler function for all these intents and call common parameterized function from inside. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using paramerized functions or classes is a good practice. With this setup you can easily re-use any required logic if two intents perform similair actions in the webhook. 
If you require some different behaviour you can enter values into the parameters, an example of this would be a function that ends the conversation.

```
    app.intent("Stop Conversation"), (conv) => {
      const message = "Okay, have a nice day";
      endConversation(conv, message);
    });

    app.intent("Cancel Reservation"), (conv) => {
      const message = "Okay, I will cancel your reservation. Have a nice day."

      endConversation(conv, message)
    });

    endConversation(conv, message) {
      conv.close(message);
    }
```

You could choose to go for one single handler that looks up the intent name and then fetches the response, but this can cause some issues when working with [Helper intents](http://That%20setup%20is%20fine.%20You%20could%20choose%20to%20go%20for%20one%20single%20function%20that%20handles%20all%20the%20calls,%20but%20this%20can%20create%20issues%20when%20handeling%20helper%20intents%20intent%20calls%20such%20as%20accountlinking%20or%20click%20events%20for%20Google%20Assistant.%20https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/helpers#helper_intents_2). These Helper intents require extra parameters that normal intents do no use, so you will have to account for them in your common handler or write seperate handlers for them. If you do not need these intents, then there isn't any harm in using a single handler.

---

One extra thing to note, having 100 intents is quite alot. Remember that intents should be used to indicate what you user says and not as a step in your flow. Usually this means that you only have one intent to handle yes input from your users and you will use [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview) to detirmine which step of the conversation you are in.

Comment: Sample Code Implementation with common function handlers: -  
  intentMap.set('Share the Experience',commonfunction);
  intentMap.set('FAQ Share the Experience - yes',commonfunction);
  intentMap.set('FAQ Share the Experience - no',commonfunction);
  intentMap.set('FAQ Share the Experience - yes - custom - yes',commonfunction);
  intentMap.set('FAQ Share the Experience - yes - custom - no',commonfunction);
  intentMap.set('FAQ Share the Experience - yes - custom - no - custom - yes',commonfunction);

Comment: When i say 100 intents, i have included the 10 followup intents part of one intent as well. So, can i just have one function and use below code to fetch intent name and
  fetch intent anme specific response from database?
  
  const intent = request.body.queryResult.intent.displayName;
  
  Database table structure: -
  intent_name|| intent_response
  'Share the Experience'||'Please tell me your experience?'

Comment: If you have any extra information or code that you wish to add to your question, please edit your question and add it there. It's alot clearer if you do that instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [actions-on-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) or [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment) libraries, then yes, having an Intent Handler for each Intent and having those handlers call other functions with the parameters you want is the best approach.

However... if you're not using these libraries, you certainly have other options available.

For example, using [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) you can set builder functions that extract parameters into the request environment and make the database call. If you set the "Action" field in Dialogflow you can (but don't have to) use this as the basis for an Action Handler.

If you just want to stick to your own libraries, you can parse the JSON yourself and make whatever function calls based on whatever values you wish.

Comment: What if I have more than 200 intents and I am using below syntax: -intentmap.set(intentname,functionname); Shall i call a common function from all the 200 intents and fetch intent name and based on intent name get its response stored in my database. 1

request.body.queryResult.intent.displayName

What do you suggest?
Option1:
Having 200 function handlers for each intent and calling a common parameterized function with intent name as input and getting response from database table.
Option2: -
Just one common function for all of the intents and fetch intent name and get their response.

Comment: You should probably update your question to add that information so it is more clear. It is difficult to read that as part of a comment and figure out what you mean.